# Google Cloud Storage restrict download usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Is there a way to restrict the GCP Storage bucket to a specific domain, Android/iOS app etc. so that only those entities be allowed to use this particular bucket's resources?

Comment: Can you give more information on what you know on the requesters? have they Google Account? Are they authenticated? Is the bucket public?

Comment: The user can be but is not required to be authenticated, but I would like the bucket to be restricted or be able to be used only via app from the Store.

Comment: I think that if you want to do this, you would need to authenticate your user, either if you use [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-explicit-python) or plan on granting this to only [authenticated users](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#identities), I think you will have more control

Answer (score 0):

If the user aren't always authenticated, there isn't strong security, only small thing to increase the difficulty to pass through...

I recommend you to [serve your assets behind a HTTPS load balancer with the bucket as backend](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets) (like a static website).

The main reason is the capacity to use Cloud Armor and to customize the policy to catch and check one of the [request attribute](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#attributes). I think you can achieve something with the request header, either with a custom header that you set in your application, or to reuse the Application specific headers (I'm not a mobile developer, but I know that Android has. I'm sure Ios also).

It's not very strong, but it let you the capacity to test easily and to reduce the capacity of anyone to get the content.